# jQuery extract text within double quotes

Tags: jquery, regex

I have large HTML files with traditional double quotes like `“` and closing as `”` how can I extract **plain text** within those double quotes?

Unfortunately quote open and quote close are not in same p tag.

My HTML is something like this

```
<p>“And, as best friends, you would have shopped lots of times before, wouldn’t you? You’re best friends?</p>
<p>---Yes but not before that time, not before she gave birth to Shelby we weren’t shopping as much.</p>
<p>Not as much?</p>
<p>---No.”</p>
```

Finally what I want to achieve from this is I should trim all the tags with double quotes so that full text within double quotes will be in one `p` tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
var str = '<p>“And, as best friends, you would have shopped lots of times before, wouldn’t you? You’re best friends?</p><p>---Yes but not before that time, not before she gave birth to Shelby we weren’t shopping as much.</p><p>Not as much?</p><p>---No.”</p>';

// get text within quotes
var String=str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('“')+1,str.lastIndexOf('”'));

// now to strip tags
String = String.replace(/<p>/g, '');
String = String.replace(/<\/p>/g, '');
console.log(String);
```

Comment: Actually question is not to strip quotes but to strip p tags

Comment: Updated answer for you

Answer (score 0):

Try with this script:

```
var text = "";
$("p").each(function(){
    text += $(this).text().trim();
}
text = text.substring(1, text.length-1); //Removes last and first character
console.log(text);
```

Here the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7m0LjeLr/11/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bunch of such a small dialogs in your html file the following idea might work. First extract text from p-tags. Then group them by starting and closing qoutes. For example using `Array.prototype.reduce`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/orkvL3bj/).

```
$('p') //find tags
.toArray() //make array
.map(function(p){
    return $(p).text();
}) //extract text
.reduce((function(){ 
    var collecting = 0, buffer = [];
    function begin(txt) { //start grouping
        if(collecting) throw new Error('Incorrect opening quote');
        collecting = 1;
        buffer = [txt];
    }
    function end(text) { //end grouping
        if(!collecting) throw new Error('Incorrect closing quote');
        buffer.push(text);
        var txt = buffer.join('\n');
        collecting = 0;
        buffer = [];
        return txt;
    }
    return function(arr, text) { //reducer
        var start = text.indexOf('“') >= 0,
            stop = text.indexOf('”') >= 0;
        if(start) {            
            begin(text);            
        }
        else if(stop) {
            arr.push(end(text));    
        }
        else {
            buffer.push(text);    
        }

        return arr;
    };
}()), []); //group by quotes
```